# Paste output stream to the current writing place

Tags: 20.04, output, paste

I want to have a script .sh(which will be binded to hotkey) which pasts text from file, it should work like ctrl + v. I need something like `cat` which pasts output not in terminal, but any application(for ex: browser).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are there any bash commands that could help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xclip` or `xsel` to manipulate the clipboard from the command line. To paste, there is no other option than to issue a paste command in the application. There, you can use a bash tool such as `xdotool` or `xvkbd` to send a hotkey combination to the application, typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Following two lines (not counting the shebang) will load a text file to the clip board and send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel -bi < /home/user/Documents/filename.txt
xdotool key Control+v
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the thing I was looking for